# Trouble with uploading Large files with gdrive php client

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am getting the below error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Failed to parse Content-Range header.' in vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118

Stack trace:

> 0 vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), NULL)
>
> 1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), NULL)
>
> 2 vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(176): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> 3 vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58):Google_Task_Runner-run()
>
> 4 vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(788): Google_Http_R in /var/www/html/website-redesign/application/libraries/hla_app_log/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118

Code for uploading:

```
function uploadInBatch($client,$service, $parentId,$backup_file) {

$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->title = 'backup.sql';
$file->setParents(array($parentId));
$filesize = filesize($backup_file);

$chunkSizeBytes = $filesize/20;

// Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
$client->setDefer(true);
$request = $service->files->create($file);

// Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
  $client,
  $request,
  'application/sql',
  null,
  true,
  $chunkSizeBytes
);
$media->setFileSize($filesize);

$status = false;
$handle = fopen($backup_file, "rb");

$chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
$status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
$resumeUri = $media->getResumeUri();
$offset = ftell($handle);

while (!$status) {

    if($resumeUri){
        $result = $media->resume($resumeUri);
    }
    
    fseek($handle, $offset);   
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    if(!$status){ //nextChunk() returns 'false' whenever the upload is still in progress
        echo 'sucessfully uploaded ' . ($media->getProgress()/$filesize)*100 . ' %';
    }
    
}
fclose($handle);
// Reset to the client to execute requests immediately in the future.
$client->setDefer(false);
}
```

The above function is used to upload files with around 2GB

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before its like the API doesn't let you upload really large files.

You might consider following the example found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video) it looks a bit different from your code.

```
// Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }
```

Comment: i have tried this, this code gets exited with another error , where the last chunk always gets rejected because of some reason

Comment: And if you use a smaller file?   What happends if you reduce your chunk size?

Comment: for smaller files, i am directly uploading without using chunks, and its working perfectly fine, for larger files if i use smallest size for chunk (256kb) then also same problem, after approx 99%, its getting returned with this error

Comment: My experience says that anything over 2 gb normally crashes but the documentation says that you should be able to upload up to 5 tb.   Let me try and get some feed back from someone at Google

Comment: thanks very much, i tried a file with 1.9gb even that didn't work